# print an icard in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I want to create a PDF file with Icard showing in it.

Following is the code:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font custFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font() { Size=6f};
int borderSize = 1;
Document IcardDoc = new Document(PageSize.HALFLETTER);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(IcardDoc, Response.OutputStream);
IcardDoc.Open();

PdfPTable icardTable = new PdfPTable(2);
iTextSharp.text.Image logoImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/images/logo.jpg"));
logoImage.WidthPercentage = 15f;
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(logoImage, false);
cell.PaddingLeft = 10f;
cell.PaddingTop = 10f;
cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
cell.PaddingRight = 10f;
cell.Colspan = 2;
cell.Border = 0;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
icardTable.AddCell(cell);
icardTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name:", custFont)) { Border = borderSize });
icardTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(student.firstname + " " + student.lastname, custFont)) { Border = borderSize });
```

The print document size will be 8.5 cm in height and 5.4 cm in width.

So need to fit it that way, is there any solution to this because the above code is not fitting the table on page and in proper size?

Any other format will also do like word etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out the solution :

```
Document IcardDoc = new Document(new Retangele(200f, 315f),35f,35f,0f,0f);
```

and adjust the width of the table accordingly:

```
PdfPTable icardTable = new PdfPTable(2);
icardTable.WidthPercentage = 140f;
```

to fit table exactly on page, if decrease rectangle `width` then increase table `WidthPercentage` and vice versa.
You also need to care of left and right margins defined as 35f in `Document` class constructor

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1042, 651);
var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(pgSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: How does a 1042x651 document relate to *8.5 cm in height and 5.4 cm in width* as requested in the question?